# DNN "Welcome to your new website" Pop Up

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

"Welcome to your new website" popup in DNN 7.2 and above shows some dynamic content. Its visible only to host users and doesn't reappears if "don't show this again" checkbox is checked once.

I need to develop something on similar lines where a popup should appear every-time a user of specific role(and some business logic) logs in. I think about creating a custom module and add it to all pages which could this for me but it seems welcome to your new site popup already tackles this.

Now I need to know if its somehow feasible to alter or extend this popup as per my need. I googled for some time and went through quick search in DNN code but haven't found anything convincing on this. Please suggest if what I think with this popup is feasible or I am searching in wrong path and creating custom module is my only way.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the best way to handle this would be with a custom skin object, and a custom module to manage the announcements.